# Sql Random Data Check

Tags: ios, sql, random

I have a database for my game on iOS. I pull out my data randomly with:

```
SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE Category IS 2 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

Is there any way to check the previous data that comes up and do not show it again?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to store the previously selected row ID and exclude it from your list.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (tablename) 
WHERE (rowname) IS (data)
and (tablename.id) != (PreviousID)
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Bill thank you for your quick response. Can you please be more sufficient because it's my first attempt with sql. My question is what exactly is on my table the field (PreviusID)?

Comment: I thought you were asking a specific question about a specific table, and had only listed (tablename) to be generic.  Each table should have a primary key defined for it.  You could hold onto this primary key in your application, and then when going back to the source you could include "and tablename.id != PreviousID".

Comment: Bill in my case i have two tables, the first is with two columns (ID), and (Names) which is the names of the categories and the second Table has a foreign key with name Category to the first table on the (ID) and then the Columns (Question), (Answer 1), (Answer 2), (Answer 3), (Answer 4). I Edited my question if you can understand now. I am trying when comes up the next random question to not be the same record with the previus one.

Comment: Doesn't your Question table have a primary key?  It should.  What I am suggesting is that you always store the PreviousID as the last retrieved primary key of the question table.  Then you can be certain that the next time you select you won't pull the same question you just selected from.  This is not a SQL only solution, you'll need to keep up with the previous ID in your ObjectiveC code.

Comment: No right now on questions table i have only the foreign key to the first table Categories. Is there any way to achieve my goal through sql or i have to implement my objective c Code?

Comment: SQL has no concept of "except the last result".  Each query is stateless.  If you want to maintain state between queries, that has to be done in objective C.  And I strongly encourage you to add a PK to all of your DB tables.

Comment: Ok thank you very much Bill. I'll see how to figure tha out. Thank you again.